# Using dplyr to fill in missing values (through a join?)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame (df1) that has some missing values (city, state):

```
SiteID    City          StateBasedIn   Lat  Lon   Var1 Var2
4227      Richmond      KY            -39  -113   6    0
4987      Nashville     TN            -33  -97    7    0
4000      Newark        NJ            -39  -95    8    0
4925      Miami         FL            -40  -99    0    0
4437      Montgomery    AL            -32  -117   4    1
4053      Jonesboro     AR            -30  -98    8    1

df1 <- structure(list(SiteID = c(4227L, 4987L, 4000L, 4925L, 4437L, 
4053L, 4482L, 4037L, 4020L, 1787L, 2805L, 3025L, 3027L, 3028L, 
3029L, 3030L, 3031L, 3033L), City = structure(c(10L, 7L, 8L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Arcata", "Jackson", "Jonesboro", "Miami", "Montgomery", "Nashville", 
"Newark", "Portland", "Richmond"), class = "factor"), StateBasedIn = structure(c(6L, 
10L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "AL", "AR", "CA", "FL", "KY", "MS", "NJ", 
"OR", "TN"), class = "factor"), Lat = c(-39L, -33L, -39L, -40L, 
-32L, -30L, -38L, -31L, -35L, -38L, -30L, -39L, -38L, -32L, -39L, 
-31L, -38L, -34L), Lon = c(-113L, -97L, -95L, -99L, -117L, -98L, 
-98L, -95L, -112L, -120L, -114L, -81L, -117L, -90L, -109L, -115L, 
-81L, -104L), Var1 = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 3L), Var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("SiteID", 
"City", "StateBasedIn", "Lat", "Lon", "Var1", "Var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

And I would like to fill those values in by merging with another data frame (df2) that has 3 of the same columns, but not all of the columns that are in df1:

```
SiteID       City         StateBasedIn
1787         Lusby        MD
2805         Springdale   AR
3025         Saukville    WI
3027         Saukville    WI
3028         Saukville    WI
3029         Saukville    WI

df2 <- structure(list(SiteID = c(1787L, 2805L, 3025L, 3027L, 3028L, 
3029L, 3030L, 3031L, 3033L), City = structure(c("Lusby", "Springdale", 
"Saukville", "Saukville", "Saukville", "Saukville", "Saukville", 
"Mequon", "Mequon"), .Dim = c(9L, 1L)), StateBasedIn = structure(c("MD", 
"AR", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI"), .Dim = c(9L, 
1L))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("SiteID", 
"City", "StateBasedIn"))
```

So basically I would retain all of the information in df1, and input the missing values that are available from df2. As I'm not too familiar with all of the dplyr options yet, I tried the different 'join' options but had no luck. I also tried to use 'merge' in the base package but still no success. Is there another way to do this (preferably with dplyr)?

Comment: FYI: your `df2` is not a proper data.frame; the second two columns are matrices.

Comment: Jason, etiquette on SO dictates that you accept one of the answers provided. Not only does it acknowledge to others who follow with the same dilemma as you that the problem was resolved by one or more of the answers, but it also "rewards" those who volunteer their time to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not very stylish, but at least it is a solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

aux <- df1 %>% 
  # filter missing values
  filter(City == "") %>%
  # delete City and StateBasedIn so that the columns 
  # are not duplicates after the join
  select(-c(City, StateBasedIn)) %>%
  # inner join with the second dataframe
  inner_join(df2, by = "SiteID") %>%
  # change order of the columns
  select(SiteID, City, StateBasedIn, Lat, Lon, Var1, Var2)

df1 %<>%
  # filter all rows which values are not missing
  filter(City != "") %>%
  # bind the auxiliary dataframe
  rbind(aux)
```

Results in:

```
 SiteID       City StateBasedIn Lat  Lon Var1 Var2
1    4227   Richmond           KY -39 -113    6    0
2    4987  Nashville           TN -33  -97    7    0
3    4000     Newark           NJ -39  -95    8    0
4    4925      Miami           FL -40  -99    0    0
5    4437 Montgomery           AL -32 -117    4    1
6    4053  Jonesboro           AR -30  -98    8    1
7    4482     Arcata           CA -38  -98    1    1
8    4037   Portland           OR -31  -95    8    1
9    4020    Jackson           MS -35 -112    0    1
10   1787      Lusby           MD -38 -120    3    0
11   2805 Springdale           AR -30 -114    3    1
12   3025  Saukville           WI -39  -81    7    1
13   3027  Saukville           WI -38 -117    4    0
14   3028  Saukville           WI -32  -90    8    0
15   3029  Saukville           WI -39 -109    0    1
16   3030  Saukville           WI -31 -115    8    0
17   3031     Mequon           WI -38  -81    1    1
18   3033     Mequon           WI -34 -104    3    0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `full_join` from `dplyr`, along with `replace` and `coalesce` to put together a pretty concise solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 

# Cleaning from r2evans (if you want to keep it to dplyr just use r2evans lapply method

df1 <- mutate_if(df1, is.factor, as.character)
df2 <- dmap(df2, as.vector)

full_join(df1, df2, by = "SiteID") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("City","StateBased")), funs(replace(., . == "", NA))) %>% 
  mutate(City = coalesce(City.y, City.x),
         StateBasedIn = coalesce(StateBasedIn.y, StateBasedIn.x)) %>% 
  select(-contains("."))
```

Comment: How to automate the routine for non-manual input of the variables in mutate coalesce function?

Comment: the answer seems a bit outdated by now? Do you mean `map_dfc` instad of `dmap`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simplified version of Felix's answer.

First, repairing the data by changing `factor` to `character`, and removing the apparent matrices from the second one:

```
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 18 obs. of  7 variables:
#  $ SiteID      : int  4227 4987 4000 4925 4437 4053 4482 4037 4020 1787 ...
#  $ City        : Factor w/ 10 levels "","Arcata","Jackson",..: 10 7 8 5 6 4 2 9 3 1 ...
#  $ StateBasedIn: Factor w/ 10 levels "","AL","AR","CA",..: 6 10 8 5 2 3 4 9 7 1 ...
#  $ Lat         : int  -39 -33 -39 -40 -32 -30 -38 -31 -35 -38 ...
#  $ Lon         : int  -113 -97 -95 -99 -117 -98 -98 -95 -112 -120 ...
#  $ Var1        : int  6 7 8 0 4 8 1 8 0 3 ...
#  $ Var2        : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ SiteID      : int  1787 2805 3025 3027 3028 3029 3030 3031 3033
#  $ City        : chr [1:9, 1] "Lusby" "Springdale" "Saukville" "Saukville" ...
#  $ StateBasedIn: chr [1:9, 1] "MD" "AR" "WI" "WI" ...

df1 <- mutate_if(df1, is.factor, as.character)
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.vector)
```

Now the work:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(select(df2, SiteID, cty = City, st = StateBasedIn), by = "SiteID") %>%
  mutate(
    City         = ifelse(nzchar(City), City, cty), 
    StateBasedIn = ifelse(grepl("[^\\s]", StateBasedIn), StateBasedIn, st)
  ) %>%
  select(-cty, -st)
#    SiteID       City StateBasedIn Lat  Lon Var1 Var2
# 1    4227   Richmond           KY -39 -113    6    0
# 2    4987  Nashville           TN -33  -97    7    0
# 3    4000     Newark           NJ -39  -95    8    0
# 4    4925      Miami           FL -40  -99    0    0
# 5    4437 Montgomery           AL -32 -117    4    1
# 6    4053  Jonesboro           AR -30  -98    8    1
# 7    4482     Arcata           CA -38  -98    1    1
# 8    4037   Portland           OR -31  -95    8    1
# 9    4020    Jackson           MS -35 -112    0    1
# 10   1787      Lusby           MD -38 -120    3    0
# 11   2805 Springdale           AR -30 -114    3    1
# 12   3025  Saukville           WI -39  -81    7    1
# 13   3027  Saukville           WI -38 -117    4    0
# 14   3028  Saukville           WI -32  -90    8    0
# 15   3029  Saukville           WI -39 -109    0    1
# 16   3030  Saukville           WI -31 -115    8    0
# 17   3031     Mequon           WI -38  -81    1    1
# 18   3033     Mequon           WI -34 -104    3    0
```

I included two different ways to check for empty fields, uncertain if your example was conveniently clean in that regard; you can use either `nzchar` (empty vs non-empty) or the `grepl("[^\\s]",...)` solution (some non-whitespace present) easily. (Some data might also need `is.na` in the check ...)