# Routine for non-manual argument of a set of variables in coalesce() dplyr function

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

I have a list of dfs to be combined into one. These dfs have some matching columns and rows and some distinct or missing ones.

The minimum structure (for understanding) of the first two dfs.

df1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6),
    Name = c("LI","NO","WH","MA","BU","SO","FO","AT","CO","IN","SP","CE"),
    H_A = c("H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A"),
    W = c(15, 13, 5, 13, 9, 12, 10, 13, 1, 8, 4, 2),
    X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 7, 5, 13, 1, 3),
    Y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
  row.names = c(NA,-12L),  class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df2:

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    Name = c("LI","NO", "WH", "MA", "BU", "SO"),
    H_A = c("H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A"),
    W = c(15, 13, 5, 13, 9, 12),
    X = c(10, 12, 11, 15, 6, 14),
    Z = c(4, 14, 16, 16, 25, 30)),
  row.names = c(NA,-6L),class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This can be solved with this alternative:

```
df_combined <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id", "Name", "H_A")) %>% 
  mutate(X = coalesce(X.x, X.y),
         W = coalesce(W.x, W.y)) %>% 
  select(-contains("."))
```

I would like to automate the routine for non-manual input of the variables in mutate coalesce function. After all, there are several variables for the context X and W above. In addition to this I will continue the routine for df3, df4, df5 that have the same minimal matching with df1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins by their nature don't natively fill in positions we have to implement a fix to solve this problem, and although you can use if else statements as shown in the answer above, `coalesce()` is a much cleaner function to use.

See this post here for another example (could potentially be seen as a repeated question).

[Using dplyr to fill in missing values (through a join?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683837/using-dplyr-to-fill-in-missing-values-through-a-join)

```
library(tidyverse)


df_test <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id", "Name", "H_A")) %>% 
  mutate(X = coalesce(X.x, X.y),
         W = coalesce(W.x, W.y)) %>% 
  select(id, Name, H_A, W, X, Y, Z)

df_test == df_combined

      id Name  H_A    W    X    Y    Z
 [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [7,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
 [8,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
 [9,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
[10,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
[11,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
[12,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

NA's expectedly return NA as you can't match two NA's together using a simple `==` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join` from `dplyr` and substitute NA's like this, where I am guessing `Id` and `H_A` together make a key value:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6),
                      Name = c("LI","NO","WH","MA","BU","SO","FO","AT","CO","IN","SP","CE"),
                      H_A = c("H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A"),
                      W = c(15, 13, 5, 13, 9, 12, 10, 13, 1, 8, 4, 2),
                      X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 7, 5, 13, 1, 3),
                      Y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                 row.names = c(NA,-12L),  class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                      Name = c("LI","NO", "WH", "MA", "BU", "SO"),
                      H_A = c("H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "A"),
                      W = c(15, 13, 5, 13, 9, 12),
                      X = c(10, 12, 11, 15, 6, 14),
                      Z = c(4, 14, 16, 16, 25, 30)),
                 row.names = c(NA,-6L),class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df_combined <- left_join(df1, 
                         df2 %>% 
                           select(id, H_A, "df2_X" = X, Z))  %>%
  mutate(X = if_else(is.na(X), df2_X, X)) %>% 
  select(-df2_X)
#> Joining, by = c("id", "H_A")

df_combined
#> # A tibble: 12 × 7
#>       id Name  H_A       W     X     Y     Z
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 LI    H        15    10     0     4
#>  2     1 NO    A        13    12     0    14
#>  3     2 WH    H         5    11     0    16
#>  4     2 MA    A        13    15     0    16
#>  5     3 BU    H         9     6     0    25
#>  6     3 SO    A        12    14     0    30
#>  7     4 FO    H        10    12    NA    NA
#>  8     4 AT    A        13     7    NA    NA
#>  9     5 CO    H         1     5    NA    NA
#> 10     5 IN    A         8    13    NA    NA
#> 11     6 SP    H         4     1    NA    NA
#> 12     6 CE    A         2     3    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
# perform an update join, overwriting NA-values in W, X and Y, and 
# adding Z, based on key-columns ID, Name and H_A
df1[df2, `:=`(W = ifelse(is.na(W), i.W, W), 
              X = ifelse(is.na(X), i.X, X),
              Y = ifelse(is.na(Y), i.Y, Y),
              Z = i.Z),
    on = .(id, Name, H_A)][]

# id Name H_A  W  X  Y  Z
# 1:  1   LI   H 15 10  0  4
# 2:  1   NO   A 13 12  0 14
# 3:  2   WH   H  5 11  0 16
# 4:  2   MA   A 13 15  0 16
# 5:  3   BU   H  9  6  0 25
# 6:  3   SO   A 12 14  0 30
# 7:  4   FO   H 10 12 NA NA
# 8:  4   AT   A 13  7 NA NA
# 9:  5   CO   H  1  5 NA NA
#10:  5   IN   A  8 13 NA NA
#11:  6   SP   H  4  1 NA NA
#12:  6   CE   A  2  3 NA NA
```